# Running forward prop function after loading a tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, model, neural-network

I am unable to run the forward propagation function after loading my saved Tensorflow model. I am able to successfully extract the weights, however when I try to pass new inputs to forward prop function it throws an 'Attempting to use uninitialized value' error.

My placeholders are as follows:

```
x = tf.placeholder('int64', [None, 4], name='input')  # Number of examples x features
y = tf.placeholder('int64', [None, 1], name='output')  # Number of examples x output
```

Forward prop function:

```
def forwardProp(x, y):

    embedding_mat = tf.get_variable("EM", shape=[total_vocab, e_features], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(seed=1))

    # m x words x total_vocab * total_vocab x e_features = m x words x e_features
    # embed_x = tf.tensordot(x, tf.transpose(embedding_mat), axes=[[2], [0]])
    # embed_y = tf.tensordot(y, tf.transpose(embedding_mat), axes=[[2], [0]])

    embed_x = tf.gather(embedding_mat, x)  # m x words x e_features
    embed_y = tf.gather(embedding_mat, y)  # m x words x e_features

    #print("Shape of embed x", embed_x.get_shape())

    W1 = tf.get_variable("W1", shape=[n1, e_features], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(seed=1))
    B1 = tf.get_variable("b1", shape=[1, 4, n1], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

    # m x words x e_features *  e_features x n1 = m x words x n1
    Z1 = tf.add(tf.tensordot(embed_x, tf.transpose(W1), axes=[[2], [0]]), B1, )
    A1 = tf.nn.tanh(Z1)

    W2 = tf.get_variable("W2", shape=[n2, n1], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(seed=1))
    B2 = tf.get_variable("B2", shape=[1, 4, n2], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

    # m x words x n1 *  n1 x n2 = m x words x n2
    Z2 = tf.add(tf.tensordot(A1, tf.transpose(W2), axes=[[2], [0]]), B2)
    A2 = tf.nn.tanh(Z2)

    W3 = tf.get_variable("W3", shape=[n3, n2], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(seed=1))
    B3 = tf.get_variable("B3", shape=[1, 4, n3], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

    # m x words x n2  * n2 x n3 = m x words x n3
    Z3 = tf.add(tf.tensordot(A2, tf.transpose(W3), axes=[[2], [0]]), B3)
    A3 = tf.nn.tanh(Z3)

    # Convert m x words x n3 to m x n3

    x_final = tf.reduce_mean(A3, axis=1)
    y_final = tf.reduce_mean(embed_y, axis=1)

    return x_final, y_final
```

Back prop function:

```
def backProp(X_index, Y_index):
    x_final, y_final = forwardProp(x, y)
    cost = tf.nn.l2_loss(x_final - y_final)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    total_batches = math.floor(m/batch_size)


    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)

        for epoch in range(epochs):
            batch_start = 0

            for i in range(int(m/batch_size)):

                x_hot = X_index[batch_start: batch_start + batch_size]
                y_hot = Y_index[batch_start: batch_start + batch_size]
                batch_start += batch_size

                _, temp_cost = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: x_hot, y: y_hot})

                print("Cost at minibatch:  ", i , " and epoch ", epoch, " is ", temp_cost)

            if m % batch_size != 0:
                x_hot = X_index[batch_start: batch_start+m - (batch_size*total_batches)]
                y_hot = Y_index[batch_start: batch_start+m - (batch_size*total_batches)]
                _, temp_cost = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: x_hot, y: y_hot})
                print("Cost at minibatch: (beyond floor)  and epoch ", epoch, " is ", temp_cost)


        # Saving the model
        save_path = saver.save(sess, "./model_neural_embeddingV1.ckpt")
        print("Model saved!")
```

The model is reloaded by calling the predict function:

```
def predict_search():

    # Initialize variables
    total_features = 4
    extra = len(word_to_indice)
    query = input('Enter your query')
    words = word_tokenize(query)
    # For now, it will throw an error if a word not present in dictionary is present
    features = [word_to_indice[w.lower()] for w in words]
    len_features = len(features)
    X_query = []
    Y_query = [[0]]  # Dummy variable, we don't care about the Y query while doing prediction
    if len_features < total_features:
        features += [extra] * (total_features - len_features)
    elif len_features > total_features:
        features = features[:total_features]

    X_query.append(features)
    X_query = np.array(X_query)
    print(X_query)
    Y_query = np.array(Y_query)

    # Load the model

    init_global = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    init_local = tf.local_variables_initializer()

    #X_final, Y_final = forwardProp(x, y)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_global)
        sess.run(init_local)
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./model_neural_embeddingV1.ckpt.meta')
        saver.restore(sess, './model_neural_embeddingV1.ckpt')
        print("Model loaded")
        print("Loaded variables are: ")
        print(tf.trainable_variables())
        print(sess.graph.get_operations())
        embedMat = sess.run('EM:0')  # Get the word embedding matrix
        W1 = sess.run('W1:0')
        b1 = sess.run('b1:0')
        W2 = sess.run('W2:0')
        b2 = sess.run('B2:0')
        print(b2)
        W3 = sess.run('W3:0')
        b3 = sess.run('B3:0')

        **#This part is not working, calling forward prop gives an 'attempting to use uninitialized value' error.** 
        X_final = sess.run(forwardProp(x, y), feed_dict={x: X_query, y: Y_query})

        print(X_final)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accidentally creating a bunch of graph variables with the `forwardProp` function after loading them from the meta graph, effectively duplicating your variables without intending to do so.

You should refactor your code to follow the best practice of creating your graph variables before you ever create a session.

For example, create all your variables in a function called `build_graph`. You may call `build_graph` before creating your session, but never afterwards. This will avoid confusion like this.

You should almost always avoid calling a function from `sess.run` such as you are doing with:

```
X_final = sess.run(forwardProp(x, y), feed_dict={x: X_query, y: Y_query})
```

You're asking for bugs that way.

Note what happens in `forwardProp(x, y)` you are creating tensorflow constructs, all your weights and biases.

But notice that you created those in these two lines of code:

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./model_neural_embeddingV1.ckpt.meta')
saver.restore(sess, './model_neural_embeddingV1.ckpt')
```

Another options, which may be what you were trying to do, is to not use `import_meta_graph`. You can create all your tensorflow OPs and variables, then run `saver.restore` to restore the checkpoint, which will map the checkpoint data into the variables you already created.

Notice that you actually have 2 options in tensorflow here, and that's a little confusing. You've ended up doing both (importing the graph which contains all your OPs and variables), as well as re-creating the graph. You have to pick one.

I usually go with the first option, don't use `import_meta_graph`, just re-create the graph programmatically by calling your `build_graph` function. Then call `saver.restore` to bring the checkpoint in. You will, of course, re-use your `build_graph` function for training and as well as inference time so you end up with the same graph both times.

Comment: Thanks, that works! So, the basic idea is to recreate the graph first by calling the appropriate functions and then load the saved model right?

Comment: Yes, that's probably the easiest method to follow. Importing the meta graph is equivalent to re-creating the variables, so you have to choose one XOR the other, less you end up with two sets of variables as you did.